# Handling nvarchar parameter vs decimal

Tags: sql-server

This works:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
declare @minAmount decimal

set @sql = N'select PRODUCTGROUP
             from dbo.ICMaster
             where ONHAND > @minAmount'

set @minAmount = 400

print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@minAmount decimal', @minAmount
```

But as soon as I change the `@minAmount` to `nvarchar`, it does not (no errors but the output is null). What am I missing ?

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

declare @minAmount nvarchar(100)

set @sql = N'select PRODUCTGROUP
             from dbo.ICMaster
             where PRODUCTGROUP = @minAmount'

set @minAmount = '400'

print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@minAmount nvarchar', @minAmount
```

I also tried :

```
set @minAmount = char(39)+'400'+char(39)
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is how to make the above code work with an nvarchar @minAmount parameter as opposed to decimal.  BTW, it works fine when replacing parameter:  select 
 PRODUCTGROUP
from 
 dbo.ICMaster
where 
 PRODUCTGROUP = '400'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you query `PRODUCTGROUP` for is `4` not `400` because you forgot a size for the `nvarchar`:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@minAmount nvarchar(4000)', @minAmount
```